# How to change (-,+) symbol with a button Bootstrap Accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

I have created a boostrap 4 accordion menu with + and - symbol. The symbol changes as it is collapsed and uncollapsed.

I add the symbol with :after

However I would like to replace it with a button rather than a '-,+' symbol.
So that there will be 2 buttons for me and it will be like "See more","See less" ( It can be same button with different text and background ) and change as I click

I couldn't figure it out.

My code and demo : https://www.codeply.com/go/sOps2WhtG5

```
<div class="container">
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div class="card mb-0">
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <a class="card-title">
                Item 1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            <a class="card-title">
              Item 2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
            <a class="card-title">
              Item 3
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <div class="card-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. samus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css

```
.accordion .card-header:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';  
    content: "\f068";
    float: right; 
}
.accordion .card-header.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\f067"; 
}
```

Comment: Try replacing the css content property with '+' or '-'

Comment: @AswinKumar But I would like to replace it with a button rather than just text. Sİnce I cannot put html of a button to content, somehow I supposed I have to put it with js or something.

Comment: Still not clear what you are expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you are using the `div.card-header` as the collapse toggle; Do you intend on limiting the toggle trigger to the button only? If so, consider changing your `a.card-title` to  `div.card-title` and add your `button` within. Then adjust your css to `.card-header button:after`. Please note you should only use the `href` attribute on an anchor tag (you have it on your `div.card-header`) and for the `button` element you would use `data-target`. You can review the [documentation here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#example).

If your intent is to have more complex markup (not just plain text label) then you will need a js solution. (I can assist with that as well)

HTH

```css
.accordion .card-header button:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';  
    content: "\f068";
}
.accordion .card-header button.collapsed:after {
    content: "\f067";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div class="card mb-0">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                Item 1
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
              Item 2
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
            aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
            craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Probably should include the [documentation example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/)

Comment: This example is pretty good but it is not exactly an "Accordion" it is like a toggle box. All I ask is to have the button that you have shown in your demo, replaced by +,-  in my example. I don't have to use content to show the 'content', but I couldn't fix it by just changing it to a div or something.

Comment: @SNaRe I've updated my example. Let me know if its that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.accordion .card-header:after {
    content: "See less";
    float: right; 
}
.accordion .card-header.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "See more"; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div class="card mb-0">
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
            <a class="card-title">
                Item 1
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            <a class="card-title">
              Item 2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
            <a class="card-title">
              Item 3
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <div class="card-body">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. samus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this one solution for it. I hope this would be help

Comment: But I would like to replace it with a button rather than just text. Sİnce I cannot put html of a button to content, somehow I supposed I have to put it with js or something.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.accordion .card-header button:after {
    content: "See less";
}
.accordion .card-header button.collapsed:after {
    content: "See more";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
<div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <div class="card mb-0">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
                Item 1
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
            <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
                aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
                craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
              Item 2
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
        <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt
            aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat
            craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have adapted the code to meet your requirements, with due credit to above answers from `@jcruz` and `@uday`.